# How to minimize the actions in the UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am working on an app and I want to display in a gridview (created programmatically) some images that will appear randomly. I have the images saved in the drawables folder and I get the image's name from a database. **The problem that I have is that it takes too much time to get the data from the database (list), reorganize it randomly and create the views of the gridView.** 
I have tried to get the random list using an async task but I get a nullPointerException when I start to create the gridView because the list isn't still created. And if I wait until the list is created I end with the same problem.

I am going to explain you how is the game, that will help you to understand why I am making the randomly reorganization in the activity.

In the database I have pairs of characters (victim and murderer), I have more than I ask for in the activity, because I want to get different characters each time I open the application. So from the database I get a random list of paired characters(victims and murderers). After that, I have to display them in the gridView and they must be disordered, this is the method that I think is time consuming (actually is this method and the SQLite database query). I have to reorganize twice the list, because I need to have the same amount of victims and murderers.

I will show you now the code that I am using

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            Intent intent = getIntent();
            numRows = intent.getIntExtra("NumRows", 1);
            numColumns = intent.getIntExtra("NumColumns", 1);
            totalTime = intent.getIntExtra("Time", 30);
            level = intent.getIntExtra("Level", 1);

            ....
            new PrepareListMurder(this, level, numRows, numColumns).execute();

            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            mGridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

            mGridLayout.setColumnCount(numColumns);
            mGridLayout.setRowCount(numRows);

            //DBUtilities = DataBaseUtilities.getInstance(this);

            Point size = new Point();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            int screenWidth = size.x;
            int screenHeight = size.y;
            int margin = 10;
            for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<numColumns; j++){
                    int aux = i;
                    GridLayout.Spec row = spec(i);
                    GridLayout.Spec col = spec(j);
                    ImageView img = createImageView(pos);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = createParams(row, col, margin, screenWidth, screenHeight);
                    mGridLayout.addView(img, params);
                    pos++;      }


            }
```

These are the methods to create the imageView and the LayoutParams. (The subList is the randomly ordered list containing the names of the characters, I am supposed to get it with the async task

```
private ImageView createImageView(int pos){
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    String character = subList.get(pos);
    Log.d("lista", subList.toString());
    int img_id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(character.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_"), "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    img.setImageResource(img_id);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    img.setOnClickListener(this);
    img.setTag(character);
    return img;
}
private GridLayout.LayoutParams createParams(GridLayout.Spec row, GridLayout.Spec col, int margin, int screenWidth, int screenHeight){
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
    params.width = screenWidth / numColumns - 2*margin;
    params.height = screenHeight / numRows - 2*margin;
    params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    return params;
}
```

And this is the code for creating the List of characters

```
public class PrepareListMurder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;
    private String errorMesaje;
    private int level;
    private int numRows;
    private int numColumns;


    public PrepareListMurder(Context context, int level, int nR, int nC){
        this.context = context;
        this.level = level;
        this.numColumns = nC;
        this.numRows = nR;
    }



    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DataBaseUtilities DBUtilities = DataBaseUtilities.getInstance(context);
        ArrayList<String> mMurderVictimList = DBUtilities.getSelectedMurderStringList(level);
        List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>(mMurderVictimList.subList(0,numRows*numColumns));
        Collections.shuffle(subList);
        return subList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> chars) {
        super.onPostExecute(chars);
        ((CallBackFile) context).createListMurder(chars);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

The code that I am using in the doInBackground() is what I had before in the onCreate() of the activity, but the activity took too long to open and if I wanted to display a "big" gridView with 4 rows and 4 cols crashed and I get a  **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** (works fine with less columns or rows).

How can I do it?

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Read about multithreading in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before charging the image in the imageView, I have read the bitmap dimensions and I have loaded a scale down version into memory [as is recommended in android developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Thanks to that I have avoid the problem of running out of memory without increasing the heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read this full available on Google Books lecture

[Anders Goransson, Efficient Android Threading: Asynchronous Processing Techniques for Android](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y6KfAwAAQBAJ&pg=PP2&dq=efficient+programming+android&hl=pl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Hope it help